# Jqgrid: Multiselect in toolbar filter

Tags: css, jqgrid, multi-select

I want to add multiple select to my toolbar filter, since it is not supported natively by the JQrid.
The best and the easiest will be reuse the ui.multiselect plugin which comes together, however, im not able to succeed with that.

My idea was to render what comes together with searchoptions (I did simplified example to make it more clear):

```
searchoptions:{multiple:true, value:'true:true;false:false', defaultValue:'false'}
```

and then run multiselect rendering on given column:

```
$("#gs_Example").multiselect()
```

But instead of expected dropdownbox I got something as ugly as that picture:
http://i38.tinypic.com/2zgvuh3.jpg

I cannnot bring mutliselect frame to the foreground or whatsoever...

```
<div class="ui-multiselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget" style="width: 146px;">
<div class="selected">
<div class="actions ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
<span class="count">1 items selected</span>
<a class="remove-all" href="#">Remove all</a>
</div>
<ul class="selected connected-list" style="height: 1px;">
<li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-element" title="false" style="">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden"></span>
false
<a class="action" href="#">
<span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="available">
<div class="actions ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
<ul class="available connected-list" style="height: 1px;">
</div>
</div>
```